Does a defamatory statement have to be public?
(US context)
Most of the time, defamation suits seem to involve writings or statements that are read or heard by members of the public. I know that in specific situations--say employment--someone might allege a statement to be defamatory, but it is promulgated to only certain people, e.g. the person's managers, and it seems that that is generally privileged.
Consider records that are generally privileged. The specific example I am thinking of is a hospital record about a patient. A medical consultant at the hospital writes something in that record that is false and extremely negative, and the person writing it made no attempt to confirm its accuracy. But while that person is a patient that statement is read and heard by various people who have legitimate access to that record, with resulting negative effects on the patient's care and how hospital staff interact with him.
The hospital answers that the statements were not published to a third party, but several people had access to the statements in the record. In particular, the patient's attending physicians have read the consultation report.

The way you use public seems wrong. Wouldn't it be public if others saw it, even if it is not as public as some?

I am sorry, but what is the question?

Yes
I can write in my diary as much smack about you as I want. I can call you up and read my diary to you. I can attach it to an email and send it to you.
It isn’t defamation until I give it to someone who isn’t me or you. It doesn’t have to be a lot of people - one will be enough.
From your example, if anyone but the consultant read a defamatory statement, that’s defamation. However, just because something is nasty doesn’t make it defamatory.
First it has to be a statement of fact, not opinion. If I call someone a child molester, that’s a statement of fact and I better have proof that the person has a conviction for that. However, if I say someone is an unpleasant, disagreeable, son-of-a-bitch, that’s an opinion and isn’t defamatory. It’s quite likely that what a medical practitioner writes in the notes are just opinions.
There are also a number of other defences to defamation.

"I better have proof that the person has a conviction for that" Credible evidence that you committed that crime without a conviction wouldn't be defamatory in most cases. Certainly, for example, you can accuse someone publicly of something based upon your own personal experience.

@ohwilleke true enough, forgive the hyperbole

A patient was assigned to a unit which, although not a locked unit, had controlled access and video monitoring in the rooms. The unit was apparently used for medical patients who were also mentally ill or were for other reasons likely to either wander or act out. A surgeon did a consult unrelated to any cognitive or behavioral issues. She wrote that security was posted outside his room (not literally true) due to his "reported history" including "sometimes violent" behavior. No such history in med record and no actual history of violence.
